# Real-time procedural sounds with Python?

Tags: python, audio

I want to do procedural sounds in Python, and instantly play them back rather than save them to a file. What should I be using for this? Can I just use built-in modules, or will I need anything extra?

I will probably want to change pitch, volume, things like that.

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy along with [`scikits.audiolab`](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/) should do the trick.  `audiolab` has a [`play`](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/fullapi.html#scikits.audiolab.play) function which supports the ALSA and Core Audio backends.

Here's an example of how you might produce a simple sine wave using numpy:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def testsignal(hz,amplitude = .5,seconds=5.,sr=44100.):
    '''
    Create a sine wave at hz for n seconds
    '''
    # cycles per sample
    cps = hz / sr
    # total samples
    ts = seconds * sr
    return amplitude * np.sin(np.arange(0,ts*cps,cps) * (2*np.pi))
```

To create five seconds of a sine wave at 440 hz and listen to it, you'd do:

```
>>> from scikits.audiolab import play
>>> samples = testsignal(440)
>>> play(samples)
```

Note that `play` is a blocking call. Control won't be returned to your code until the sound has completed playing.

Comment: Seemed great, until I realised it was Mac OS and Linux only. (I'm running windows)

Comment: Repeated calls to play() have audible gaps between them... unless I'm missing something, this isn't going to work for any real-time application where you want to have a continuous stream of varying sound...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Python wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).  Particularly the "Music programming in Python" section.

Answer (score 0):

Pyglet could be a good option as it embeds functions for audio procedural: 
[Pyglet/media_procedural](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/media_procedural.html)