# Real-time procedural sounds with Ruby

Tags: ruby, real-time, audio

There is this question posted here in SO: [Real-time procedural sounds with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773487/real-time-procedural-sounds-with-python)

I have the same question but for Ruby, i have searched quite thoroughly but haven't found anything convincing.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)." We need to know where you've looked, what you've tried, and basically, what does "searched quite thoroughly" mean?

Comment: i can do beeps in realtime but there is an audible gap between beeps. I can also create a nice wav file with several ruby libraries, but these libraries (ruby-audio, ruby wave-file ruby-midi) dont seem to handle outputting sound in realtime